# YouTube DATA API V3 does not return refresh token

Tags: laravel, youtube-data-api, google-client

I have almost looked through all the answers to this question and have not been able to solve my problem. I tried different options but can't get refresh token. Here's an example of my code.

```
$googleClient = new \Google_Client();
$redirectUrl = url('***');
$googleClient->setClientId(config('services.google_api_key.client_id'));
$googleClient->setClientSecret(config('services.google_api_key.client_secret'));
$googleClient->setScopes(config('services.google_api_key.scopes'));
$redirect = filter_var($redirectUrl);
$googleClient->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$googleClient->setAccessType('offline');
$googleClient->setApprovalPrompt('force');

if ($request->has('code')) {
    $googleClient->authenticate($request->get('code'));
    $token = $googleClient->getAccessToken();
    dd($token);
}
```

And it returned only these data

```
[
  "access_token" => "***"
  "expires_in" => 3599
  "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
  "token_type" => "Bearer"
  "created" => 1613189613
]
```

I know that the refresh token is provided only on the first call, and so I tried to use this method `$googleClient->revokeToken($token);` to get it again, but it didn't help, and I already spent a whole day trying to solve this problem and could not. Please help me solve this problem. I understand that I am making a mistake somewhere, but I cannot understand where. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem and would like to explain in detail what was the reason, maybe someone else will come in handy. And so I created everything as it was described in the official documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#obtainingaccesstokens.
I used this code and was unable to get the refresh token.

```
$googleClient = new \Google_Client();
$redirectUrl = url('***');
$googleClient->setClientId(config('services.google_api_key.client_id'));
$googleClient->setClientSecret(config('services.google_api_key.client_secret'));
$googleClient->setScopes(config('services.google_api_key.scopes'));
$redirect = filter_var($redirectUrl);
$googleClient->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$googleClient->setAccessType('offline');
$googleClient->setApprovalPrompt('force');

if ($request->has('code')) {
    $googleClient->authenticate($request->get('code'));
    $token = $googleClient->getAccessToken();
    dd($token);
}
```

The official documentation says this:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
$client->addScope(GOOGLE_SERVICE_YOUTUBE::YOUTUBE_FORCE_SSL);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
// offline access will give you both an access and refresh token so that
// your app can refresh the access token without user interaction.
$client->setAccessType('offline');
// Using "consent" ensures that your application always receives a refresh token.
// If you are not using offline access, you can omit this.
$client->setApprovalPrompt("consent");
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
```

Pay attention to this part:

```
// Using "consent" ensures that your application always receives a refresh token.
// If you are not using offline access, you can omit this.
$client->setApprovalPrompt("consent");
```

And this is what I managed to find out

```
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force'); // works
$client->setApprovalPrompt('consent'); // doesn't work
$client->setPrompt('consent'); // works
```

For **'consent'** `setApprovalPrompt()` doesn't work, but I could not find about it in the official documentation. And found this error from here https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1795.
My final code looks like this which works fine and returns me a refresh token:

```
$redirectUrl = url('my_callback_url');
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(config('services.google_api_key.client_id'));
$client->setClientSecret(config('services.google_api_key.client_secret'));
$client->addScope(config('services.google_api_key.scopes'));
$client->setState(substr(md5(time()), 0, 15));
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectUrl);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('consent');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
return $client->createAuthUrl();
```

Thank you **stvar** for your answer, after that I started to read the documentation all over again and look for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

adding consent prompt fixed the issue. for js library it will look like this:

```
const authorizationUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  // 'offline' will get refresh_token
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: scopes,
  prompt: 'consent',
  state: stateName,
});
```